# Google fonts working on localhost but not on live server

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-font-api

I added google font "Raleway" to my Nextjs app. The fonts changed in my local server but does not show on the live environment after running npm build.

Please adivse.

Please Help

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
export default function Document() {
return (
<Html>
  <Head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link
      rel="preconnect"
      href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"
      crossOrigin="true"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@100;200;300;400&family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </Head>
  <body>
    <Main />
    <NextScript />
  </body>
</Html>
);
}


Css 
html,
body {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 }
```

Comment: It's work on production environment but not work on localhost for me

Answer (score 0):

Google fonts sometimes don't change when your are not using internet.

Comment: But they're saying that they work on their localhost, but _not_ the live environment—which, I think, we can assume is connected to the internet if they're able to connect to it via a browser.

Comment: localhost is active until you don't clear your browsing history

Comment: I checked with another system and its still not working on live environment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).